# Resize D3 Chart to Parent in React

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reactjs

I was working through the tutorial from: http://ahmadchatha.com/writings/article1.html

And it sets you up with a React Component like this:

```
class SimplePie extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-xs-4 chart"
        style={{background: this.props.data[1]}} >
        {this.props.title}
        <D3Chart
          width={200}
          height={200}>
          <DataSeries
            data={this.props.data[0]}
            colors={colors}
            width={200} height={200} />
        </D3Chart>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But I want to change this so the D3Chart will resize based on the size of parent, and listen for resize events.  Is there any easy way to do this in React?

I am struggling with event listeners for resize events on a particular div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measuring sizes of elements with React is not as straight forward as you might think, the main reason for this is that React doesn't really care about sizes, you must read them from the DOM, after they are drawn.

For your case here we can utilize the `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle functions and a vanilla JavaScript `resize event` on the `window` element, like so:

```
class SimplePie extends React.Component {
  constructor (props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
           width: 200,
           height: 200
        };
    this.measure = this.measure.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillMount () {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.measure, false);
  }
  componentWillUnmount () {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.measure, false);
  }
  measure () {
    let rect = this.container.getBoundingClientRect();
    if(this.state.width !== rect.width || this.state.height !== rect.height){
       this.setState({
              width: rect.width, 
              height: rect.height
           });
    }
  }
  componentDidMount (){
     this.measure();
  }
  componentDidUpdate (){
     this.measure();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={(container)=>{this.container = container}} style={{width: "100%", height: 300}} className="col-xs-4 chart"
        style={{background: this.props.data[1]}} >
        {this.props.title}
        <D3Chart
          width={this.state.width}
          height={this.state.height}>
          <DataSeries
            data={this.props.data[0]}
            colors={colors}
            width={this.state.width} height={this.state.height} />
        </D3Chart>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Edit:** The container must have a fixed width and height, if you want to use percentage based height you must set the height of the parent of this component.

Comment: This wasn't quite working for me, the component just kept resizing bigger and bigger to fit the div

Comment: @Rob keep in mind that your div that is the main container must have a fixed width and height, meaning that they must be set in the style of the div either from CSS or from inline styles, those could be 100%. If you don't specify a fixed width and height the container will grow based on content.